# Oracle SQL - How to find the difference between two date variables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to find the longest period of time in between the order date and ship date times. I understand the method of getting it, but I am just unsure about it. Im using the JustLee Book Order Database for this one
Here is my code

```
SELECT o.ORDER#, o.ORDERDATE, o.SHIPDATE, o.SHIPCITY, o.SHIPSTATE
FROM ORDERS o;
WHERE (SELECT
```

I would have liked to give you a better result of my query but I am stuck on the dates. Any help is good help. Tank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the difference between two `DATE` data type values, just subtract one from the other.

```sql
SELECT ORDER#,
       ORDERDATE,
       SHIPDATE,
       SHIPCITY,
       SHIPSTATE,
       SHIPDATE - ORDERDATE AS days_between_ship_and_order
FROM   ORDERS;
```

If you want to find the maximum, then from Oracle 12, you can order the results in descending order of difference and use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to row(s) find only the largest difference.

```sql
SELECT ORDER#,
       ORDERDATE,
       SHIPDATE,
       SHIPCITY,
       SHIPSTATE,
       SHIPDATE - ORDERDATE AS days_between_ship_and_order
FROM   ORDERS
ORDER BY days_between_ship_and_order DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES ONLY;
```

Comment: This works, but I am trying to only get the longest date between the orders

Comment: @Laser As I said in the answer, `ORDER BY days_between_ship_and_order DESC` then `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES ONLY`.